# Glassfish ejb ref resolution error for remote business interface

Tags: glassfish, ejb-3.0, jndi

I've created very basic EJB3 stateful bean but can't access it remotely.
I'm getting:

> Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: ejb ref resolution error for remote business interfacecom.s9120.ejb.Calculator [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.s9120.ejb.Calculator]

I have 1 bean and 1 interface.
It looks like the interface is not deployed (I'm using GlassFish):
Here is the code:

```
package com.calc.ejb;

import javax.ejb.Remote;

@Remote
public interface Calculator {

    public Double multiply(Double multiplier, Double multiplicand);
    public Double divide(Double dividend, Double divisor);
    public Double add(Double addend, Double augend);
    public Double subtract(Double minuend, Double subtrahend);

    public void saveToMemory(Double number);
    public Double retrieveFromMemory();
}
```

Bean:

```
package com.calc.ejb;

import javax.ejb.Remote;
import javax.ejb.Stateful;

/**
 * Session Bean implementation class CalculatorBean
 */
@Stateful
@Remote(Calculator.class)
public class CalculatorBean implements Calculator{
/* Implementation */
}
```

Accessing it:

```
context = new InitialContext(); 
Calculator calculator = (Calculator) context.lookup("java:global/Zad3_s9120/CalculatorBean");
```

Do I have to do some steps to make interface available to session bean?
I'm adding it from Eclipse with "Add and Remove" server menu.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From what I can see, you have different packages.

You've defined interface as:

```
com.calc.ejb.Calculator
```

but your exception tells you about:

```
com.s9120.ejb.Calculator
```

Perhaps you don't have appropriate class in your client project?

BTW: You don't need to specify `@Remote` on both - the interface and EJB. You can do only `@Remote(MyClass.class)` on EJB or `@Remote` on interface.

Comment: The problem was that I didn't have correct "Calculator" interface on my client - I just copied one from EJB, so although I had the interface on my client it was from different package thus couldn't been found.